# Linker error on compile time?

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator

```
 error: unable to open executable '/Users/mac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hftpysylqrrbjoanrgzctdxelpxr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.app/ProjectName'
```

What i have to do in this situation,As per the answer of the same question ,I cleared the derived data and then deleted the app from the device after that its not working still problem arising.

Comment: hftpysylqrrbjoanrgzctdxelpxr

Comment: that is a project name i was hided that @trojanfoe

Comment: It's not helpful.  Does the file exist?  Does the project/target name match the file/path names?  Only you know these things.

Comment: yes the file already exist and the project name matches with the path name.

Comment: Please post the complete linker command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86682/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-trojanfoe).